# How to use routes starting with same string

Tags: react-router

Is there any way how to create two different pages starting with same sring - GuidePage and GuideDetailPage using react router?

My code doesn't work, after open `/guide` it shows `GuidePage` components, it's ok. But after open `/guide/detail` it shows `GuidePage` NOT `GuideDetailPage`.

What is wrong?

```
            <Router history={history}>
                <main>
                    <MenuHeader />
                    <Switch> 

                        <Route path='/guide'>
                            <Route path='/' component={GuidePage} />
                            <Route path='/detail' component={GuideDetailPage} />
                        </Route>

                        <Redirect to='/home' />
                    </Switch>
                    <Footer />
                </main>
            </Router>
```

So I can use `/guide-detail` for `GuideDetailPage` but I want to use `guide/detail`.

Answer (score 0):

In React Router 4, routes are dynamic instead of static, you don't need to declare all routes in one file, but declare nested route in component having those routes.

Here is Basic Example, You need to add two routes inside `Guide` Component and to make it relative use `match.path`.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/guide">Guide</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/guide" component={Guide} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Guide({ match }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Guide</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${match.url}`}>guide</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${match.url}/detail`}>Guide Detail</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <Route path={`${match.path}/detail`}
        component={GuidePage} />
      <Route
        exact
        path={match.path}
        render={() => <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function GuidePage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>GuidePage</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BasicExample;
```

Hope that helps!!!